# Foundation for sites 6 - dropdown menu - javascript can initializate

Tags: javascript, meteor, zurb-foundation

I have just started a new site created with meteor and using foundation for sites and sass.
I want to create a dropdown menu, but I can't make it work.
I followed this link
[dropdown menu](https://zurb.com/expo/lessons/how-to-re-create-top-bar-with-foundation-6) and copied html, but it's not been showed as a dropdown menu.
I think my problem is because maybe I haven't initializated the javascript of the dopdown menu.
Can someone show me how to do it. In Zurbs site there are several examples, but loading the script in the head. But I want to know how to do it with meteor.
I might be completelly lost, so any help is really welcome.

This are the packages I have added to my meteor

```
zurb:foundation-sites
seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
fourseven:scss
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the Foundation plugins you have to run the init code `$(document).foundation();`, make sure it is added after the foundation js file are included.

Comment: I had forgotten to add it to the onRendered Template.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that `$(document).foundation();` is added after DOM has been rendered (at the bottom of html) or in `window.onload` event.

Took some hours once to find this out :P